Why does “yum check dependencies” give an unclear answer?
I use the yum -d 0 -e 0 check dependencies
in order to verify if yum have conflicts with RPMs.
But when I run this on RHEL 7.2 machine I get the following:
yum -d 0 -e 0 check dependencies
containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts containerd: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts runc: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64

If we look on first line and on second line we see that RPMs are the same:
rpm -qa | grep containerd.io
containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64

What is the problem here?
and what are the solution to solve the dependencies?

You have runc installed. And you should select one of them

you means to remove the runc?

If you insist to install this software. But yum tell you you have already installed software which provide this functionality.

You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77055144/2908599
